# Resize DIV with JavaScript to Fit on Page (To print)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, printing

So I'm trying to resize two Div's that I'd like to print.

Here's the function:

```
function printDiv(printMe) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(printMe).innerHTML + $('#printMe2').html();

     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;

     }
```

This function is being called with a button onClick.

There are Two Divs in total, One of them is a calendar, and the other one is a table. The size is a bit messed up tho. It looks like this:

**Original DIV** 
[image]

**Print Version:**
[image]

I'm not so great with JavaScript, so I couldn't try too much. I've searched for relevant things, but sadly no (good) result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried setting up a print style sheet, probably better than trying to fool with javascript: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Answer (score 1):

I would create a different css file for print, its much simpler then manipulating html with javascript. here is how you do it:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="print-style.css" type="text/css" media="print" />`
or
`@media print body {}`
here is a good tutorial for print-css
http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/CSS_for_print_tutorial